# Can I get the Rising Dragon achievement with a mechanized Chilong?

Tags: achievements, xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

Is it possible to get the Rising Dragon achievement when you have turned Shaojie Zhang 'Chilong' into a MEC trooper?

I normally turn my heavies into MECs late game as the heavy bonus is great and heavies aren't so great late game.

But I found the achievement didn't pop when I brought Chilong along as a MEC last time to the "final mission" as it's the last non-multi-player achievement I need to get.

Edit: I started a fresh game and this time didn't turn Chilong into a MEC - the achievement still didn't pop. Must be some other problem.

[image]

Comment: Make sure you don't already have the achievement. Check your list, and check the list of achievements you haven't unlocked.

Comment: I've not already got the achievement - it's not in the list of locked achievements either though as it's a hidden achievement. I have 82 of 85 achievements unlocked with both "Meet New People..." & "Bubonic" showing as the only 2 locked.

Comment: i had the same problem. i think some achievements aren't working for enemy within. havent completed the mission with him yet though, just started it. hoping it works upon completion though i doubt it will. the Edison achievement didn't pop for me either even though I am certain I have ALL the upgrades in the game. think EW just has some bugs.